# how to use DLE and DC1 in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am working of conversion of stored DB2 stored procedure to postgresql stored procedures. while conversion I saw `x'10'` and `x'11'`. When i searched them, I found them to be `DLE` and `DC1`.
How can i use them in postgresql.
This is an example(in DB2) of what I was trying to convert.

```
STRING              STRING-A                        DELIMITED BY X'11'          
                    ' ) '                           DELIMITED BY SIZE           
                    X'11'                           DELIMITED BY SIZE           
             INTO  STRING-A
```

How can it be done?

Comment: That looks like Cobol, not like SQL (not even SQL for DB2)

Comment: Yes it is written in COBOL

Comment: In PL/pgSQL this would be a simple `select a,b,c into var_a, var_b, var_c  from ...` but without more context this is impossible to answer

Comment: I have to concat all of them to save them in a variable as string, But I dont know what is x'11', x'10' in postgres.